# Submit Button CSS Styles different between Mac and Windows

Tags: css, macos, button, stylesheet, reset

I have a [small demo contact form](http://byjakewithlove.com/code/ajax-contact-form/) that I'm trying to build using Ajax. When I go to style the submit button it takes the padding and font-size properly. However on my Macbook running OSX Lion the button still looks default with no padding, no larger font sizes, etc.

I have experienced this a few times and I have no idea how to fix this. CSS styles usually work the same for all operating systems and this is throwing me for a loop...

Here are two image screenshots taken from both computers so you can see what I mean.

**Windows 7**

[image: WIN7]

**OS X Lion**

[image: Mac OS X]

Is there a special property rule that I should use to reset the Mac styles? I just want to edit the submit button's font sizes, padding, color, etc. It behaves like this in all browsers, too.

Really appreciate any help on this!

EDIT: here is my code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send E-mail" id="sendbtn" class="sendbtn">
```

**CSS file**

```
form .sendbtn { display: block; font-size: 26px; padding: 3px 6px; }
```

Comment: yup just added my css and html code at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not specifying any styles that could make your buttons same across browsers. Each browser under an OS uses **default style** for the buttons (influenced by themes as well if any). You need to specify more things such as `background` , `color`, `border`, etc.

For example, this should look same across browsers:

```
form .sendbtn {
  display: block; 
  font-size: 26px; 
  padding: 3px 6px; 
  background:#eee;
  color:blue;
  border:none; /* or whatever */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add border or background property to the button's css, it'll work.